# "this" is null or gives errors - JavaScript adventures :)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am learning JavaScript and slowly wading my way to understanding why a certain page does not work :)

I am doing something like this:

```
<a onClick="removeAllMarkers(this)" href="#" >Remove All Markers</a>
```

With the idea that sending this is the correct way to go about things.  But I think I don't really understand the role of "this" in my current situation.

I am getting a JavaScript console error when I press on the link for "clear all markers" on this page:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/add_spotted_trees.php?hike_id=108

The page has login credentials: test@comehike.com | password

Any ideas what I am fundamentally doing wrong and how is the best way to clear the markers[] array?

I am currently doing something like this:

```
if (markers)
{
    for (i in markers)
    {
         markers[i].setMap(null);
         markers[i] = null;
    }
}
```

But that is precisely the part which is having the errors unfortunately.  Suggestions? :)

Here is the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting an array element to `null` won't remove it from the array.

---

To clear an array, either assign the variable to a new empty array:

```
markers = [];
```

Or set its `length` property to 0:

```
markers.length = 0;
```

Do this after looping through the array and calling `.setMap(null)` on each.

---

To only remove only the last item in an array:

```
markers.pop();
```

Comment: Thanks, it is what I was thinking, but what is puzzling me is that it says that the array is already empty.  Is it because I sent "this" into the function?  What role is the "this" playing there?  And what is wrong with the current way I am setting the array to empty? - Thanks!!

Comment: @Genadinik - `this` refers to the HTML element when used in an inline event handler such as in `onclick`. However, the `removeAllMarkers` function does nothing with it, so it really isn't doing anything here. The cause of your error is that setting array elements to `null` doesn't remove them - they are still there the next time your iterate through the array. When iterating through the array, you encounter `null` elements and try to do something with them, causing the error. I'm not sure *what* exactly is saying the array is empty because it's not ;)

Answer (score 2):

For more information see:

- [How to Clear-out/Reset An
  Array](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#quickIDX33)
- [The "this" keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)